# Converting Timer class from java to c#: scheduling tasks

Tags: c#, java, scheduling

I'm porting an application from Java to C# and I'm facing a problem connected to the different behaviors and features between the `java.util.Timer` and `System.Threading.Timer`.
In fact, in the Java version of the Timer class there's a feature (used in the original code) for scheduling tasks, that is not present in the .NET version, where it is possible to schedule one task (through a delegate function) at a time.

Is there a solution, even a small class-set to implement the feature?

I've noticed the existence of several scheduling libraries (an example is Quartz), but I would prefer a solution which would minimize the amount of code to use.

Thank you all! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use any timer class. For each scheduled task, create a new timer class and just set the *Interval* property to *(ScheduledTime - DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds* and set the *AutoReset* property to false (or the *Enabeld* property to false in the code-behind for the *Tick* event). That will execute your code once at the specified ScheduledTime.

Comment: sometimes I ask questions to StackOverflow like I would do it in real life to a friend: in fact, few minutes after I wrote it here, I elaborated a similar solution to the one you described here... :)

Answer (score 1):

There are at least 4 timers in .NET. Your short answer: use System.Threading.Timer. I'd recommend reading about the timers here [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx), as well as looking into System.Windows.Threading.DispatchTimer (part of WPF) which can dispatch events at particular times, but does so on the UI thread.